# "Turning off" $(window).on('before unload') When Not Needed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

I'm creating a survey that offers one question at a time. I want to alert the user if they try and leave before it's over (WORKING) but allow them to leave after the last question (NOT WORKING).

Of course if there are more elegant ways of doing this than what's below, I'm open to suggestions.

Here's what I have:

Page1.php

Contains the following JS and a div to hold the questions loaded from page Page2.php using .html().

```
function window_on(e) {

    if (e=='turnon') {
        alert(e); // THIS I RECEIVED
        $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        return 'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?';
        });
    } else {
        alert(e); // THIS I DO NOT RECEIVE
        $(window).off('beforeunload');
    }

}
```

Page2.php

I get the "turnon" alert each time Page2.php loads EXCEPT for when the survey is over. I should get the "turnoff" alert then, but don't. AND I still get the popup if I try and leave the page.

Everything works except for window_on('turnoff').

```
<?php
if ($next_q=='end') { // IF END ?>
   <script>
   window_on('turnoff'); // FOR TESTING 
   add_progress(<?php echo $progress; ?>) // WORKING
   </script>

<?php } else { ?>

   <script>
   add_progress(<?php echo $progress; ?>) // WORKING
   window_on('turnon'); // FOR TESTING 
   </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could you post the code that sets $next_q ?
I'm a little rusty with js, but it would seem to me like $next_q isn't set to "end" correctly.

Comment: And what code calls your last code block?  How is that code triggered?

Comment: $next_q is definitely being set to 'end' (I had some php code that printed it out) and "window_on('turn on')" is not firing like it does with the loading of every other question. I know this because I don't get the "turnon" alert.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why the above doesn't work, but I figured out a way to do it. I moved window_on('turnoff') from Page2.php to inside the add_progress() function on Page1.php. Now when the progress reaches 100 it triggers window_on('turnoff').